# executing code taking too much time

Tags: java, sql

Below is a part of my code.When I run the code it takes too much time to be executed (more than 8 minutes). After few tests, I found out that delay caused by each while loop. I tried to move the queries inside the loop but that was useless.
Any idea how I can reduce the delay?

```
sql="update rpttbl set cutsum= ? where temp=?";
            prepStmt=conCreate.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs=rptStmt.executeQuery("select temp from rpttbl");
            prepStmt2=createDBcon.prepareStatement("select sum(la2a) from "+Globals.comp+".sarchivelist where lempid= ? and "
                        + "(ldate='"+Globals.year+"-"+Globals.date+"-28') and (la5=22 or la5=33 or la5=2) ");
            while(rs.next()){
                prepStmt2.setString(1, rs.getString(1));
                prepStmt2.execute();
                rs2=prepStmt2.getResultSet();
                prepStmt.setString(2, rs.getString(1));
                if(!rs2.next()){
                }  
                else{
                    prepStmt.setString(1,rs2.getString(1));
                    prepStmt.addBatch();
                }
                prepStmt.executeBatch();
            }

            sql="update rpttbl set promir= ? where temp=?";
            prepStmt=conCreate.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs=rptStmt.executeQuery("select temp from rpttbl");
            prepStmt2=createDBcon.prepareStatement("select la2a from "+Globals.comp+".sarchivelist where lempid= ? and "
                        + "(ldate='"+Globals.year+"-"+Globals.date+"-28') and la6=6 ");
            while(rs.next()){
                prepStmt2.setString(1, rs.getString(1));
                prepStmt2.execute();
                rs2=prepStmt2.getResultSet();
                prepStmt.setString(2, rs.getString(1));
                if(!rs2.next()){
                }  
                else{
                    prepStmt.setString(1,rs2.getString(1));
                    prepStmt.addBatch();
                }
                prepStmt.executeBatch();
            }


            sql="update rpttbl set proch= ? where temp=?";
            prepStmt=conCreate.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs=rptStmt.executeQuery("select temp from rpttbl");
            prepStmt2=createDBcon.prepareStatement("select sum(la2a) from "+Globals.comp+".sarchivelist where lempid= ? and "
                        + "(ldate='"+Globals.year+"-"+Globals.date+"-28') and la6=10001 ");
            while(rs.next()){
                prepStmt2.setString(1, rs.getString(1));
                prepStmt2.execute();
                rs2=prepStmt2.getResultSet();
                prepStmt.setString(2, rs.getString(1));
                if(!rs2.next()){
                }  
                else{
                    prepStmt.setString(1,rs2.getString(1));
                    prepStmt.addBatch();
                }
                prepStmt.executeBatch();
            }
```

edit:
I moved prepStmt.executeBatch(); outside the while() loop, but that didn't reduce the delay.

Comment: Which part of the `while` is taking so much time? The fact that there is a very high number of records or the call to `executeBatch`? Can `executeBatch` be deferred to after the loop, for example? Or can you do `prepStmt1` and `prepStmt2` in one move by changing the query?

Comment: You're executing the batch every single loop. That's not batching, that's executing one query at a time.

Comment: Also, instead of "testing" run a profiler and check what is actually taking so long.

Comment: prepStmt.executeBatch(); takes 5790 milliseconds !!!
note that I moved prepStmt.executeBatch(); outside the while() loop.

Answer (score 0):

execute the prepStmt.executeBatch(); outside the while() loop

Comment: you are using single preparestatement for 3 loops, so try to excute that batch after the 3 while() loops

Comment: it didn't help!